# ValueError: logits and labels must have the same shape ((1, 7, 7, 2) vs (1, 2))

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm quite new to CNN.
I'm trying to create a the following model. but I get the following error: "ValueError: logits and labels must have the same shape ((1, 7, 7, 2) vs (1, 2))"

Below the code I'm trying to implement

```
#create the training data set
train_data=scaled_data[0:training_data_len,:]
#define the number of periods
n_periods=28
#split the data into x_train and y_train data set
x_train=[]
y_train=[]

for i in range(n_periods,len(train_data)):
    x_train.append(train_data[i-n_periods:i,:28])
    y_train.append(train_data[i,29])

x_train=np.array(x_train)
y_train=np.array(y_train)

#Reshape the train data
x_train=x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0],x_train.shape[1],x_train.shape[2],1)
x_train.shape
y_train = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train,2)

# x_train as the folllowing shape (3561, 28, 28, 1)
# y_train as the following shape (3561, 2, 2)

#Build the 2 D CNN model for regression
model= Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32,kernel_size=(3,3),padding='same',activation='relu',input_shape=(x_train.shape[1],x_train.shape[2],1)))
model.add(Conv2D(64,kernel_size=(3,3),padding='same',activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(4,4)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Dense(128,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(64, activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='sigmoid'))
model.summary()

#compile the model
model.compile(optimizer='ADADELTA', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

#train the model

model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=1, epochs=1, verbose=2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems in your approach:

1. You're using Convolutional/MaxPooling layers in which the inputs/outputs are as matrices, i.e., with the shape of (Batch_Size, Height, Width, Depth). You then add some Dense layers which usually expect vectors, not matrices as inputs. Therefore, you have to first *flatten* the outputs of MaxPooling before giving it to Dense layer, i.e., add a `model.add(Flatten())` after `model.add(Dropout(0.25))` and before `model.add(Dense(128,activation='relu'))`.
2. You are doing binary classification, i.e., you have two classes. You are using `binary_crossentropy` as the loss function, for this to work, you should keep your targets as they are (`0` and `1`) and not use `y_train = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train,2)`. Your final layer should have `1` neuron and not `2` (Change `model.add(Dense(2, activation='sigmoid'))` into `model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))` )